# Cannot find pythonwin on my ArcGIS 10.1?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, installation, pythonwin

What is the version for the Python in ArcGIS 10.1 and what is the build ? My laptop does not show having pythonwin in the folder under

C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin.

Is there something I need to re install or install the latest version or build for that software ?

Comment: Never mind.  Figured it out and had to download from this site http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20218/   that does it .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With ArcGIS 10.1, the Python Win 32 extension is not included within the software installation exactable.

> Note: The PythonWin32 extension setup requires an existing
>   installation of Python 2.7 which is installed after installing ArcGIS
>   Desktop, ArcGIS Engine and ArcGIS Server setups.
>
> ArcGIS no longer installs PythonWin because the recommended
>   methodology for creating the geoprocessor has changed to using a new
>   Python module that ESRI has developed to support the latest version of
>   Python and multiple platforms, such as Windows, UNIX and Linux.

Here are the instructions for PythonWin installation:

1. Make sure you have ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 installed
2. Open up ArcCatalog 10.1

Next, you need to know what version of PythonWin to install, 32 or 64 bit.  To check this, we will run a quick python script (your first python script!).

3. Click on the Python icon   and type in these two statements

   Import sys
4. Then, click the return button on your keyboard.
5. Next type in:

   print(sys.version)
6. Then, click the return button on your keyboard.

You should now see a print out on your screen showing your computer operating system processor (32 or 64 bit)

Next, download the PythonWin executable.

7. Got to:

   http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/
8. Click on the latest build parent folder (Build 219)
9. Depending on your computer operating system being 32 or 64 bit download either:

pywin32-219.win-amd64-py2.7.exe

OR

pywin32-219.win32-py2.7.exe

10. Run and install the .exe
11. Take all default installation paths
12. After installation has finished running successfully, within your windows explorer browse to:

C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin

Folder and double click on the Pythonwin.exe to open the software